# Delphi 2007 Build from Project menu (shift F9) doesn't rebuild all units

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I have had this problem since day one with Delphi 2007.

My project has over 100 units and I know that I have some code that should generate a compiler
warning, things like variables declared never used, etc.  I want it to recompile every unit in
my project when I select 'Build' instead of 'Compile'.  I have tried deleting all of the project's
DCU files (they are in a separate folder) but that doesn't help.

From time to time after some editing it *will* show all of these compiler warnings, it just happened now, I fixed about half of them, saved the source and then did build again from the project menu and it shows only 2 hints and no warnings.

I used Delphi 5 for many years and this was never a problem, Build always did exactly that.
I have searched project options, etc to see if I'm missing something, but alas, I don't have
a clue.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong ? PLEASE ?

Thanks
JT

Comment: Are the units in question in your project file, or are they located via the search path? Not sure if that matters, just a hunch.

Comment: The question title asserts that not all units are being compiled. The question body asserts that they're being compiled, but that warnings aren't being displayed. Which is it? (It can't be both. Deleting the DCU would force compilation, assuming the unit is actually used somewhere, so if the unit weren't compiled, compilation would fail.)

Comment: My first thought was that the dcu files exist for each unit, and I am fairly sure new dcu's are only generated if a unit is modified or missing the dcu. But you have already mentioned deleting the dcu's and they still don't rebuild.

Comment: Do you have different output paths for debug vs release?  Is it possible you have DCUs in more than one place?  I would search the file system for one of the DCU filenames that doesn't recompile and see if Delphi is perhaps finding it in another locations than the spot where you deleted it.